# Cannot convert Tue Oct 07 03:00:00 EEST 2014 to Date object

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert this String "Tue Oct 07 03:00:00 EEST 2014" to a date object using this pattern: 
"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Locale here.

Eg:

```
String str = "Tue Oct 07 03:00:00 EEST 2014";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
System.out.println(df.parse(str));
```

Out put:

```
Tue Oct 07 05:30:00 IST 2014
```

From `Java` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates
>   in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text),
>   parsing (text -> date), and normalization.